# how to write lightning Component for JavaScript Button which contains sforce.Console.openSubtab() functionality?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-remoting, consoleintegrationtoolkit

we are having JavaScript Button in salesforce classic that contains functionality of

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}
{!requireScript("/support/console/31.0/integration.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/xdomain/xdomain.js")}
```

and also using this functionality to open funtion in sub tab

```
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function (result) {
 sforce.console.openSubtab();
}
```

But now we are migrating to lightning. how to achieve this type of 
functionality in lightning Component, is there any work around process

Comment: I think it is not possible. I suggest you to use lightning quickAction check this post https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-button-on-record-page-in-lightning-experience/

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Lightning Console JavaScript API for Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_getting_started.htm) in Pilot right now, I think it will be the way to go once it's GA.